# C# LINQ storing int? as int

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I am querying the database to get the **contractorid** field value, which will either return one value or null.
I need to pass that as integer onto a class method(int,int). But apparently its not matching with the methods best overload. I suspect its because the `int?` contractorid value could be null and cannot be converted to integer. But if i remove `?` and only use int then I get error about `single()` method in linq

```
    int UserID = new BussinessComponent().LoginDetails.UserID;
    using (var db = new DataContext())
    {
        int? ContractorID =
              db
                  .Users
                  .Where(x => x.UserID == UserID)
                  .Select(x => x.ContractorID)
                  .Single();


        ltlOJ.Text = DashboardComponent.GetJobs(UserID,ContractorID ).ToString();
   }
```

Comment: Try SingleOrDefault()

Comment: call the funcation as DashboardComponent.GetJobs(UserID,ContractorID??0).

Comment: @ssilas777 `SingleOrDefault` refers to the amount of rows returned not the  value. So you could get one value back but this value could be `null`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, you need to convert your `int?` to an `int` because null cannot be converted to an int.

You can do this using ['GetValueOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0(v=vs.110).aspx) to give you a default value.

```
ltlOJ.Text = DashboardComponent.GetJobs(UserID, ContractorID.GetValueOrDefault(0))
    .ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
int UserID = new BussinessComponent().LoginDetails.UserID;
using (var db = new DataContext())
{
    int ContractorID =
          db
              .Users
              .Where(x => x.UserID == UserID)
              .Select(x => x.ContractorID ?? 0)
              .Single();


    ltlOJ.Text = DashboardComponent.GetJobs(UserID,ContractorID ).ToString();
```

}

This will set the `ContracterId` local variable to `0` when its null in the DB

Answer (score 1):

You can do the job like this.

```
int? ContractorID = db
     .Users
     .Where(x => x.UserID == UserID)
     .Select(x => x.ContractorID)
     .Single() ?? -1;

int parsedValue = ContractorID.Value;
```

or maybe...

```
int? ContractorID = db
     .Users
     .Where(x => x.UserID == UserID)
     .Select(x => x.ContractorID)
     .Single()

if (ContractorID.HasValue)
    ltlOJ.Text = DashboardComponent.GetJobs(UserID,ContractorID ).ToString();
else
    // Traitment if contractorId has no value.
```

Best of luck ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are handling the case of `Single()` blowing up in your face? `Single()` will only be happy if it finds **exactly** one match. Ie 0 matches and 2 matches will make it blow up.

```
int UserID = new BussinessComponent().LoginDetails.UserID;
using (var db = new DataContext())
{
    int? ContractorID =
          db
              .Users
              .Where(x => x.UserID == UserID)
              .Select(x => x.ContractorID)
              .Single();

    if (ContractorID.HasValue) // check for value, since it is nullable it can be null
      ltlOJ.Text = DashboardComponent.GetJobs(UserID, ContractorID.Value).ToString();
    else
      throw new MyReasonableExceptionToThrowHere(string.Format("Missing ContractorID for UserID '{0}'", UserID));
}
```

For the `int?` itself, since it is a nullable you have to unbox it to get the inner value, this is what you are doing when you are calling `Nullable<T>.Value`. Do note that `Nullable<T>.Value` throws if the value is null, is you should always check with `Nullable<T>.HasValue` before.

Answer (score -1):

the Single() method will throw exception if can't find a match. you should consider to use SingleOrDefault()